# How to use a seq2seq model saved with .model extension in deployement

Tags: nlp, attention-model, encoder-decoder

i trained and validated my seq2seq with pointer generator network for text2sql generation and every component (embedding, encoder, decoder , attentionEncoder...) is saved with **.model** extension.

I tried to load them with torch.load and every model is a dictionary of weights; but i couldn't figure out how to use them to deploy the seq2seq model(got many errors in inputs and outputs of every model component(although the training, testing, and validation were smooth)).[the results of loading the .model components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS8hI.png)